# internal server error in heroku

Tags: heroku, laravel-5.3, jeditable

I'm currently using laravel and my website is just working fine

But upon hosting it I'm getting a problem internal server error but I figured out what the problem is, it's inside the controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $patient = Patient::find($request->id);
    $patient->$request['col'] = $request->value;
    $patient->save();
}
```

the `$request['col']` is the one i passed from my inline table editor plugin and

here is the code:

```
 $('.edit').editable('posts.update', {
 event: 'click',
 indicator : 'saving ...',
 select : true,
 submitdata : function(value, settings) {
   return {_method: "PUT",_token:token,col:$(this).attr("class").split(' ')[1]};
 },callback : function(value, settings) {
     $(this).addClass('success');
 }
 });
```

I get class of an element  `col:$(this).attr("class").split(' ')` and passing it to the update function so it will dynamically update the column of the database

But after hosting it to heroku I'm getting an error so i have tried putting a column name statically `$patient->name = $request->value;` and it's working fine then i have tried storing the name column to a variable to figure out what is really the problem `$name = 'name';` then `$patient->$name = $request->value;` then I get the error again.